# I want to move the position of the view that autolayout is specified. (ios6,xcode4.5)

Tags: ios, ios6, iphone-5, autolayout

I want to specify the coordinates in the center.

```
- (Void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.motherButton.center = CGPointMake (-100, self.motherButton.center.y);
}
```

In the above code, motherButton does not move off the screen.

How do can you go?
I want to move in the animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.motherButton.center = CGPointMake (-100, 100);
}
```

**Reason**

- `viewDidLoad` happens before autolayout is completed. So the position of the motherButton is changed by autolayout
- `viewDidAppear` happens after autolayout is completed.

**Points to Note**

1. is your project built for an older ios version ? If so, then when autolayout was enabled Xcode might have added some constraints.
2. You can always modify the constraints (autolayout) in the nib file and also programatically.  In the nib file click on each view and see the size inspector.
3. Add log messages to check the frame size and see when and where autolayout changes the frame.
4. For views that you create programatically `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`

   `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is a method defined in `UIView`/`NSView` the way to use it is `v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` where v1 is any view that was programatically created.

   Note - Xcode also has help, press Option and click on the method to know more about it
5. Watch the WWDC 2012 videos on autolayout introduction [video link to introduction to autolayout video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)

Comment: Thank you

This method worked well at first.

However, when the autolayout is working in the middle of the program and return to the original position.

only motherButton, you can not do is not affected by autolayout?

ーーー

ありがとうございます！
この方法は最初は上手くいきます。

でも、プログラムの途中でautolayoutが働いて、元の位置に戻る時があります。

motherButtonだけ、autolayoutの影響を受けなくできないですか？

Comment: modified my answer to include some possible causes (check "points to note" section)

Comment: 1
My new project
（私のプロジェクトは新しい）

2
I want to enable autolayout
（autolayoutを有効にしたいと思っている）

3
I do not know how to do
（やり方がわかりません）

4
I do not know how to use setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
（setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraintsの使い方が分からない）

5
I saw a video of WWDC2012. It was difficult.
（WWDC2012のビデオを見た。難しかった。）


only motherButton, you can not do is not affected by autolayout?
(motherButtonだけ、autolayoutの影響を受けなくできないですか？)

Comment: This video starts from the basics. See this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202. If you still can't understand, mention the slide or portion of the video (time) you can't understand. `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is a method defined in `UIView`/`NSView` the way to use it is "v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` where v1 is any view that was programatically created. Xcode also has help, press Option and click on the method to know more about it

Comment: VIDEO is difficult. Because I do not understand English.
I do not know how to use translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.

What do you for should I use?
I do I do to YES? I do I do to NO?

I tried in the following manner. I will not change anything.

     self.motherButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
     self.motherButton.center = CGPointMake (-100, self.motherButton.center.y);

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` - You should invoke this method to set it to `NO` for programmatically created views. Because the autoresizing mask naturally gives rise to constraints that fully specify a view’s position, any view that you wish to apply more flexible constraints to must be set to ignore its autoresizing mask using this method. Views created using a tool that allows setting constraints should have this set already. There are also slides in the same link (instead of the video), see if you can some kind of translator tool to translate the PDF to your language.